# Зачеркивание текста при нажатии?

Tags: html, css

У меня есть сайт, состоящий из нескольких страниц (в header есть навбар, который позволяет переключаться между страницами). 
Допустим, у меня выбрана страница, а это пункт "ALBUMS", он должен быть зачеркнут:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код страницы:

```css
.nav__link {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

.nav__link::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  animation: out 0.2s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0.58, 0.97) 1 both;
  width: 130%;
  top: 50%;
  left: -15%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header__inner">
      <div class="logo">MI MUSIC.</div>
      <nav class="nav">
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">Home</a>
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">Lives</a>
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">Albums</a>
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">News</a>
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">About</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Я пытался реализовать это все стилями, но не получилось.

Почему-то зачеркивается вообще все:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Могли бы мне помочь, пожалуйста? Я новичок, js не изучал еще.

Comment: убери `none` и поставь `text-decoration: line-through;`

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh я ему давал такой вариант но он сказал что у него остаётся перечёркивание

Comment: Можно конкретно указать первый элемент `.nav__link::first-child::after{...}` и тогда стили не будет распространяться на остальные элементы.

Comment: @bemulima  ну тогда остальные пункты не получат перечёркивание

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наверно так проще ?

И так же Вам ответ дал на toster: https://qna.habr.com/q/698443#answer_1504743

```js
let elems = [...document.querySelectorAll("nav a")];
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  elems[i].onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.classList.add("active");
  }
}
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 26px;
}

a:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.active {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">item1</a>
  <a href="#">item2</a>
  <a href="#">item3</a>
  <a href="#">item4</a>
  <a href="#">item5</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: При переходе на другую страницу, зачеркивания остаются

Comment: @penancewarrior в вашем случае зачёркиваются все потому что у вас все пункты меню имеют имя nav_link в моём случае при переходе на другую страницу не будет такого имени у пункта

Answer (score 5):

Для того, чтобы "зачёркивать" нужный пункт меню, нужно браузеру понять, что именно он должен зачеркнуть.. об этом вопроса почему-то нет, но уверен, что из-за этого у вас появляются новые "а почему не работает"..

Так вот, для того, чтобы при "активной" странице зачёркивался нужный пункт меню, нужен скрипт..
Я обычно использовал следующий: (пример на jQuery)

```
// Определим текущую ссылку
let url = location.href;
// Т.к. ссылки в меню относительные, то учитываем этот момент
url = url.split('/')[1];
// Находим ту самую ссылку, которая совпадает с ссылкой в меню
$('nav > a[href^="/'+url+'"]').addClass('active');
```

Пример работы:

```js
// Этот код ВАМ не нужен, он будет имитировать поведение браузера, чтобы показать вам работу примера
$('nav a').on('click', function(){
  $('nav a').removeClass('active');
  let url = 'www.mysite.ru'+$(this).attr('href');
  console.clear();
  console.info('> '+url);
  newPage(url);
  return false;
});

function newPage(url) {
  url = url.split('/')[1];
  console.info('this URL: '+url);
  $('nav > a[href^="/'+url+'"]').addClass('active');
} newPage('www.mysite.ru/home');
```

```css
a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.active {/* Перечёркиваем активную ссылку */
  color: red;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>
  <a href="/home">Home</a>
  <a href="/page-1">Page 1</a>
  <a href="/profile">Profile</a>
  <a href="/about">About</a>
</nav>
```

Может быть, вариант не идеальный.

---

Если у вас на странице только [якорные ссылки](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/yakorya), то там всё ещё проще:

```css
nav > a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav > a:target {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a id="home" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a id="page-1" href="#page-1">Page 1</a>
  <a id="profile" href="#profile">Profile</a>
  <a id="about" href="#about">About</a>
</nav>
```

Просто прописываете в ссылке одинаковые значения для атрибутов `href` и `id`, а после "зачёркиваете" при помощи псевдокласса [`:target`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/target)

Answer (score 2):

Что я сделал:
Собрал все `.nav__link`, прошёл по ним циклом и задал каждому элементу слушатель клика, при клике будет происходит добавление класса (или удаление, если класс есть) `.active`

У `.nav__link::after` я задал `width: 0%`, а `.nav__link.active::after`, когда у этого элемента есть класс `.active`, то элементу `::after` задаём ширину 130%.

`.nav__link::after` также я задал `transition: width 0.2s linear;`, с помощью которого анимируется `width` линейно,в течении 0.2 секунд

```js
let nav__links = document.querySelectorAll('.nav__link');

for (let i = 0; i < nav__links.length; i++) {
 nav__links[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
  nav__links[i].classList.toggle('active');
 });
}
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
 max-width: 1300px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0 10px;
}

.nav__link {
    color: black;
    margin: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase
}

.nav__link::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    background: black;
    width: 0%;
    top: 50%;
    left: -15%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    transition: width 0.2s linear;
}

.nav__link.active::after {
    width: 130%;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header__inner">
            <div class="logo">MI MUSIC.</div>
            <nav class="nav">
                <a class="nav__link" href="#">Home</a>
                <a class="nav__link" href="#">Lives</a>
                <a class="nav__link" href="#">Albums</a>
                <a class="nav__link" href="#">News</a>
                <a class="nav__link" href="#">About</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Можно сделать такое же, но при наведении(такое чаще используется на сайтах)
Тут можно обойтись без JavaScript

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
 max-width: 1300px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0 10px;
}

.nav__link {
    color: black;
    margin: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase
}

.nav__link::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    background: black;
    width: 0%;
    top: 50%;
    left: -15%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    transition: width 0.2s linear;
}

.nav__link:hover::after {
    width: 130%;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header__inner">
            <div class="logo">MI MUSIC.</div>
            <nav class="nav">
                <a class="nav__link" href="#">Home</a>
                <a class="nav__link" href="#">Lives</a>
                <a class="nav__link" href="#">Albums</a>
                <a class="nav__link" href="#">News</a>
                <a class="nav__link" href="#">About</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```